# Scraping information from the Web

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

How to get informations (http://linkWeb.com, Titles, and http://link.pdf) from this html page ?

```
<div class="title-download">
    <div id="01divTitle" class="title">
        <h3>
            <a id="01Title" onmousedown="" href="http://linkWeb.com">Titles</a>
            <span id="01LbCitation" class="citation">(<a id="01Citation" href="http://citation.com">Citations</a>)</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="01downloadDiv" class="download">
        <a id="01_downloadIcon" title="http://link.pdf" onmousedown="" target=""><img id="ctl01_icon" class="small-icon";" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've trying but it only returns the title. I'm not aware wth simple_tml_dom before. please help me. thank you :)

```
<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';
set_time_limit(0);

$url  ='http://libra.msra.cn/Search?query=data%20mining&s=0';
$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('invalid url');
foreach($html->find('div[class=title-download]') as $webLink){
    echo $webLink->plaintext.'<br>';
    echo $webLink->href.'<br>';
}

foreach($html->find('div[class=download]') as $Link2){
    echo $webLink2->href.'<br>';    
}

?>
```

Comment: With second foreach you're looking for a http://link.pdf which is specified with an attribute "title" and not with "href"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrap the titles and urls with this code :

```
foreach($html->find('span[class=citation]') as $link){
  $link = $link->prev_sibling();
  echo $link->plaintext.'<br>';
  echo $link->href.'<br>';
}
```

and to scrap the url in class download, using the answer given by @zigomir :)

```
foreach($html->find('.download a') as $link){
   echo $link->title.'<br>';    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to select an a element inside div with class title-download. At least documentation says it uses selectors like jQuery (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Try it like this:

```
$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('invalid url');
foreach($html->find('.title a') as $webLink){
    echo $webLink->plaintext.'<br>';
    echo $webLink->href.'<br>';
}

foreach($html->find('.download a') as $link){
    echo $link->title.'<br>';    
}
```

Comment: the problem is the contents of that html page have different id in every result. For example, the second result must be `id="02Title` and `id=02_downloadIcon`

Comment: so then you should select by class like this: '.title a'. I've also edited my answer.

Comment: oh yes, thank you ! but, it scraps the citations also, I just need to scrap the titles dan urls. I've found the way to scrap the titles and urls only, check out my answer. Thanks for sharing ! I get many ideas from you that make me understand how to access the HTML elements  :)

Answer (score 0):

Parse the HTML using LibXML and use XPaths to specify the elements or element attributes you want.